# Rails 3 NoMethodError (undefined method `unserialized_value' for "--- []\n":String):

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, serialization, yaml

I am using Rails 3.2.13 and postgress.
I am getting below error only in `production server`

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `unserialized_value' for "--- []\n":String):
  app/controllers/blogs_controller.rb:159:in `content_generators'
```

I am serializing Array to store it in db. Below is code.

### Controller

> ```
> class BlogsController < ApplicationController
>   def content_generators
>     @blog = Blog.find(params[:id])
>     @users = @blog.content_generators.map do |id|
>       User.find(id)
>     end
>   end
> end
> ```

### Model

```
class Blog < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :post_access, Array
  serialize :content_generators, Array
  attr_accessible :post_access, :content_generators
end
```

### Migration

```
class AddContentgeneratorsToBlog < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :blogs, :content_generators, :string, :default => [].to_yaml
  end
end
```

I have already used serialization. You can see `post_access` is serialized. And that works perfect.
But now when I added another column `content_generators` it starts breaking.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Your code is incomprehensible for me. How do you want to fetch your `@users` in `BlogsController#content_generators` action?

Comment: I want to store array of ```user_id``` in content_generators. And Yes, We can access any models in any controller action. For this case you can ignore what I do in loop, because it works perfect in development env.

Comment: What do you mean by "works perfect in development env"? These three lines seem to do something pretty different than "store array of `user_id` in `content_generators`".

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using postgresql I strongly recommend using the built in array functionality:

```
# Gemfile
gem 'postgres_ext'

class MyMigration
  def change
    add_column :my_table, :that_array_column, :text, array: true, default: []
  end
end
```

Then remove the `serialize` calls in your model and that's it. PG serialized array's behave exactly the same as YAML serialized ones on the model, except the db supports some query methods on them.